# Grabbing tag number from collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to grab the tag number of the cell I have clicked within the `collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath` function.

Here my code:

Setting of tag:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
....
   cell.tag = [theID intValue]; //SET VIDEO ID
...
}
```

The tag is needed because it is an ID I am using to send over to my server to grab information

My selector:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"%@",[[collectionView viewWithTag:indexPath] class]);

}
```

The idea is to select the `cell's` tag based on the `indexPath`

Not sure how I can accomplish this.

Sugestions? Thoughts?

Comment: Why do you need the tag, and where is the code that sets the tag? Normally tags would be used to identify elements inside of the cell, not the cell itself. Anyway, `UITableViewCell` inherits from `UIView` and therefore has a tag property accessible via `cell.tag`

Comment: [`cellForItemAtIndexPath`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/cellForItemAtIndexPath:)

Comment: @micahrosales I simply need to get the tag value that was set based on the indexPath.  But I am having difficulty doing this.

Comment: What do you mean "set based on the indexPath"? If it is just the number, `indexPath.row` and `indexPath.section` are valid here

Comment: Oh saw the question edit, sorry

Comment: @MicahRosales, sorry bad choice of words.  So an id is returned from my server in the creation of the cell and that tag is set to that ID and that is what I am trying to grab here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `UICollectionView`'s [`cellForItemAtIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/cellForItemAtIndexPath%3a), you can get the cell object.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSInteger tag = cell.tag;
    NSLog(@"%d",tag);
}
```